# Laravel whereIn does not return result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to check whether an id is in a column or not and return true or false depending on that. The problem is, the result keeps returning false even though the id is in the array.

The value for column `other_users` looks like this `["13","14"]` :

```
$user = User::where('id',auth()->user()->id)->first(); // id = 13
$consultation = Consultation::whereIn('other_users',array($user->id))->first();
if($consultation)
    $result = true;
else
    $result = false;
}

dd($result); //always return false
```

Comment: What is the type of the column `other_users` in the DB?

Comment: its varchar @ZakariaAcharki

Answer (score 2):

The `whereIn()` function will not work in this case since the target is varchar (string) you may need to use 'like' in the query, something like :

```
$consultation = Consultation::where('other_users', 'like', '%"'.$user->id.'"%')->first();
```